# Are knee voltage and Vbe the same?

Tags: transistors

I get confused by the knee voltage and Vbe. Sometimes in circuit problem question gives me knee voltage is 0.5 V and sometimes other questions just tell it like Vbe = 0.5V.

Are they both the same?

Please explain.
This is a question that confused me most.
Given IB = 25mA, Vbb = 3V Knee Voltage = 0.5V.Find the dynamic resistance.How do I solve this question

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2franfE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Knee Voltage = 0.5 V and β = 18**

Comment: There isn't really anything such as a knee voltage - it is just that at the normal currents in the range of microamps to milliamps that are used to bias transistors the vbe doesn't change more than 1-200mv. So if it is specified as 600mV or 700mV you won't be far out.

Comment: @KevinWhite, if the base has some parasitic resistance, there can be a pretty clear knee.

Comment: @ThePhoton - if anything base resistance reduces the appearance of a knee.

Comment: @Ghost, please define terms. What is Vbb? What is the circuit being asked about (please include a schematic. There is a schematic editor available when editing your question)?

Comment: You must be missing a base resistor there. You'll blow the base, Ghost. There is nothing to limit the base current.

Comment: The thing is It is missing in the actual question.As I am newbie.

Comment: Can someone please tell me whether I have subtract the knee voltage from the Base source supply or not?

Answer (score 2):

\$V_{be}\$ is whatever the voltage is between the base (b) and the emitter (e). In some circuits (or states of a circuit) it might be 0 V, in other cases it might be negative. In others it might be equal or a little bit above the knee voltage. It's unlikely to be very much above the knee voltage, because that would result in large currents flowing into the base, most likely damaging the device.